# New Relic cpu usage Heroku app

Tags: java, performance, heroku, cpu-usage, newrelic

I have simple Java EE app on Heroku. I tested this app via JMeter. And now I need measure server statistic. The most important for me is server CPU usage. I installed New Relic plugin by instructions, chapter "Add the New Relic agent as a Maven dependency". Now I examine my app in section "Applications" (categories Monitoring, Events, Reports, Settings). I need measure server CPU usage during generate requests by JMeter. Which graph or statistic is best for this purpouse. For example:

[image]

OR

[image]

OR

[image]

OR another statistic or graph is most suitable for CPU usage analysis? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New Relic can report on application server resource utilization through the application agent since the app is aware of those metrics. However, because of the unique infrastructure of the Heroku hosting platform, it is not currently possible to collect any further server metrics other than memory and load.

Please consult these docs for further info:

NR Instances Tab: http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/03/07/new-relics-instances-tab/

Heroku Runtime Metrics: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics

Comment: Thanks, I will try install Heroku Labs from your second link.